# Am I allowed to shake hands with my female friends?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, non-mahram, touching

Like a handshake or a high-five.
I heard before that its not allowed I just wanted to confirm it.

Comment: it is not allowed doing that, since they would be considered as non-mahram and ... . God willing I'll answer your question (if I was free). Good luck dear new user.

Comment: There is not much to be explained, but this one hadeeh will explain: It was narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yassaar said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “For one of you to be stabbed in the head with an iron needle is better for him than that he should touch a woman who is not permissible for him.” 

Narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Kabeer, 486. Shaykh al-Albaani said in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 5045, that this hadeeth is saheeh.

Answer (score 1):

```
                   In the name of Allah, the compassionate, the merciful
```

In regard to your question as you asked:

> Am i allowed to shake hands with my female friends?

The response of your inquiry would be NO. In truth, shaking hand is considered as a haram practice from the viewpoint and actually order of Islam. (Based on Shia view, although I assume the view of Sunni would be like that as well). Therefore you are not allowed to shake hand with your female friends, since they could be considered as non-mahram. Of course to the best of my knowledge, there are several reasons for it (as an impermissible act), but I suggest you to read the following source which has provided in Arabic, Turkish and Farsi (Persian) languages.

And God knows best

---

**Reference:**

[www.islamquest.net/ Farsi (Persian)](http://[www.islamquest.net/%20Farsi%20(Persian)][1]%20/%20[Arabic][2]%20/%20[Turkish][3])

Comment: In Shia belief... you are not allowed... yet if its going to have a SIGNIFICANT effect on your image or the image of Islam then do the handshake. i.e. you could lose your job AND you really need the money( only if finding another job isn't easy ). OR if based on your own intellect and knowing of the person if you realize that he/she would hold a grudge against Muslims afterwards then again it might be better to handshake. I usually say "I'm sorry I can't handshake with beautiful ladies, + your handshake doesn't belong to me" and they love it that way!

Comment: Nice presentation of that view! @asma22. God Bless You. و من الله توفیق

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sincere about following Shariah Law, then, it's a good question.
I am to say that It is forbidden because the female is ghaire-mahram (non-mahram), right?
There is a hadith regarding situation like this.

Ibn 'Umar (Radhiallaahu Ta'ala anhu) narrated:

> " 'Umar delivered a Khutbah to us at Al-Jabiyah. He said: 'O you people! Indeed I have stood among you as the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) stood among us, and he said: "I order you (to stick to) my Companions, then those who come after them, then those who come after them. Then lying will spread until a man will take an oath when no oath was sought from him, and a witness will testify when his testimony was not sought. **Behold! A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan.** Adhere to the Jama'ah, beware of separation, for indeed Ash-Shaitan is with one, and he is further away from two. Whoever wants the best place in Paradise, then let him stick to the Jama'ah. Whoever rejoices with his good deeds and grieves over his evil deeds, then that is the believer among you.'"
>
> > Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2165

By the way, non-mahrams are those with whom you are allowed to marry.

And Mahrams are those with whom you aren't allowed to marry. [Mahram On Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram#Who_is_mahram.3F)